# Sitecore Powershell Function piped ID string to piped Name string

Tags: powershell, sitecore

Trying to create a generic function that can accept a piped string with IDs and turn it into a piped string with the Names. The code below only returns the first item in the array. What am I missing?

```
function Get-ValuesfromID($item){
        [String[]]$allItems = $item -split "\|"
        foreach($item in $allItems)
        {
            $nameofid = (Get-Item master:\ -ID $item).Name
            $namedlist = $nameofid -join "\|"
            return $namedlist
        }
}


@{Label="Tag List"; Expression={Get-ValuesfromID($_.Tags)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement is inside the `foreach` loop. Move it outside and you should be fine. (This is why indentation is important)

```
function Get-ValuesfromID($item) {
    [String[]]$allItems = $item -split "\|"

    foreach($item in $allItems) {
        $nameofid = (Get-Item master:\ -ID $item).Name
        $namedlist = $nameofid -join "\|"
    }
    return $namedlist  # outside foreach loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It seems that the -join "|" is not appending, but it is replacing the value. I'm only getting the final time through the foreach in the return variable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `return` inside a `foreach` loop - it will exit the enclosing function / script.

`break` is needed to exit a loop; however, it seems like your intent is to *collect* all values across the loop's iterations, so the easiest approach is to enclose the entire `foreach` statement in `$(...)` and apply `-join` to the resulting array:

```
function Get-ValuesfromID ($item){

    [String[]] $allItems = $item -split '\|'

    $(foreach($item in $allItems) {
      (Get-Item master:\ -ID $item).Name
    }) -join '\|'        

}
```